# how to make images responsive in a bootstrap template

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I know this had been asked a lot and I did research and try a lot before posting this question, but nothing seems to work. I have two images and a text which I want to display all in one line. However, when I decrease my window size the images are displayed below and above the text instead of next to it. 
I have the following code and here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbedhdxo/):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <img src="image.jpg" class="images">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="text">
       <h2 class="featurette-heading">What's Included with HTML?</h2>
          <p class="lead">Tags to make words. And tons of CSS properties to style your page:</p>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Chrome Browser" class="images"></div>
</div>
```

How do I make the images resize according to the window size so that images and text are all displayed in one line?

I tried `width:100%;height auto;` and `max-width:100%;` and all sorts of combinations in order to make them responsive but it nothing worked so far.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the column size from md to xs (col-md-4 : col-xs-4).

See the [Docs](http://col-md-4).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/O0aW5qsyCkR2i7Bu-jUU1b5BWA_NygJ6ui4MgaAvL7gfqvVWqkOBscDaq4pn-vkwByUx=w300" alt="Chrome Browser" class="images img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="text">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">What's Included with HTML?</h2>

        <p class="lead">Tags to make words. And tons of CSS properties to style your page:</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/O0aW5qsyCkR2i7Bu-jUU1b5BWA_NygJ6ui4MgaAvL7gfqvVWqkOBscDaq4pn-vkwByUx=w300" alt="Chrome Browser" class="images img-responsive" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `.img-responsive` class in the image. 
This applies `max-width: 100%;, height: auto; and display: block;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

For more info:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Answer (score 1):

try replacing with
`.col-xs-12`
in image div

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class"col-sm-4 col-xs-12" on div and img-responsive class on images and a style attribut display:inline-block on img tag to keep it center.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12"">
      <img class="img-responsive"  style="display:inline-block" src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/O0aW5qsyCkR2i7Bu-jUU1b5BWA_NygJ6ui4MgaAvL7gfqvVWqkOBscDaq4pn-vkwByUx=w300" alt="Chrome Browser" class="images img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <div class="text">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">What's Included with HTML?</h2>

        <p class="lead">Tags to make words. And tons of CSS properties to style your page:</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12"">
      <img src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/O0aW5qsyCkR2i7Bu-jUU1b5BWA_NygJ6ui4MgaAvL7gfqvVWqkOBscDaq4pn-vkwByUx=w300" alt="Chrome Browser" class="images img-responsive"  style="display:inline-block" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```